# Mongodb nodejs, find and display array in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm looking for display a array in array after findOne.

Example my document:

```
"name": "test",
"Electro": [{
    "name": "test2",
    "level": "0",
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "62015643157b21f7abfcf0b0"
    },
    "build": [{
        "artifactName": "Aventurier",
        "MainStat": "HP",
        "MainStatValue": "15%",
        "SubStat1": "Crit%",
        "SubStat1Value": "30%",
        "SubStat2": "PV%",
        "SubStat2Value": "9%"
    }]
```

//////////////////////////

type is a variable (let type = Electro)

```
User.User_Characters.findOne({"name": 'test'}, {[type]:{$elemMatch:{'name': cn}}}).then(result => {
    if(result){
      console.log(result); console.log(result.Electro)
    }
```

i need console.log(result.Electro.build)

UPDATE:

resolve -> result.Electro[0], thx Joe

I have other problems :

```
User.User_Characters.findOne({"name": username}, {[type]:{$elemMatch:{'name': cn}}}).then(result => {
if(result){
 console.log(result)
```

And my result =

```
    {
  _id: new ObjectId("61fea8cfcfad2dc0c3f0f740"),
  Pyro: [
    {
      name: 'Amber',
      level: '0',
      _id: new ObjectId("62015643157b21f7abfcf0aa"),
      build: [{
        "artifactName": "Aventurier",
        "MainStat": "HP",
        "MainStatValue": "15%",
        "SubStat1": "Crit%",
        "SubStat1Value": "30%",
        "SubStat2": "PV%",
        "SubStat2Value": "9%"
    }]
    }
  ]
}
```

I just need result = build array :

```
{
  build: [{
    "artifactName": "Aventurier",
    "MainStat": "HP",
    "MainStatValue": "15%",
    "SubStat1": "Crit%",
    "SubStat1Value": "30%",
    "SubStat2": "PV%",
    "SubStat2Value": "9%"
}]
}
```

Comment: Since it is an array, can you just refer to `result.Electro[0]`?

Comment: Yes I finally found it yesterday. Thx

Comment: UP edit, it's very important :/